# Why when creating a grid for example 10x10 and drawing a random path the path is sometimes diagonal sometimes crossover the path and sometimes curved?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomPathGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int gridSize = 10;
    public int minPathLength = 5;
    public int maxPathLength = 10;
    public float squareSize = 1f;
    public Color pathColor = Color.red;
    public Color startColor = Color.green;
    public Color endColor = Color.blue;
    public float startEndRadius = 0.4f;

    private Vector2Int[] directions = { Vector2Int.up, Vector2Int.down, Vector2Int.left, Vector2Int.right };

    private Vector2Int startPoint;
    private Vector2Int endPoint;
    private Vector2Int[] path;

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), "Generate Path"))
        {
            GenerateRandomPath();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRandomPath()
    {
        ClearGrid();

        startPoint = GetRandomPointOnEdge();
        endPoint = GetRandomPointOnDifferentSide(startPoint);

        int pathLength = Random.Range(minPathLength, maxPathLength);
        path = new Vector2Int[pathLength];
        path[0] = startPoint;
        path[pathLength - 1] = endPoint;

        for (int i = 1; i < pathLength - 1; i++)
        {
            path[i] = GetRandomValidNeighbor(path[i - 1]);
        }
    }

    private Vector2Int GetRandomPointOnEdge()
    {
        int side = Random.Range(0, 4); // 0: Top, 1: Right, 2: Bottom, 3: Left

        int x, y;

        switch (side)
        {
            case 0: // Top edge
                x = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                y = gridSize - 1;
                break;
            case 1: // Right edge
                x = gridSize - 1;
                y = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                break;
            case 2: // Bottom edge
                x = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                y = 0;
                break;
            case 3: // Left edge
                x = 0;
                y = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                break;
            default:
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                break;
        }

        return new Vector2Int(x, y);
    }

    private Vector2Int GetRandomPointOnDifferentSide(Vector2Int point)
    {
        int side = Random.Range(0, 3); // 0: Top, 1: Right, 2: Bottom

        int x, y;

        switch (side)
        {
            case 0: // Top edge
                x = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                y = gridSize - 1;
                break;
            case 1: // Right edge
                x = gridSize - 1;
                y = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                break;
            case 2: // Bottom edge
                x = Random.Range(0, gridSize);
                y = 0;
                break;
            default:
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                break;
        }

        if (side % 2 == 0) // Top or Bottom side
        {
            if (point.x == x)
            {
                x = (x + 1) % gridSize;
            }
        }
        else // Right side
        {
            if (point.y == y)
            {
                y = (y + 1) % gridSize;
            }
        }

        return new Vector2Int(x, y);
    }

    private Vector2Int GetRandomValidNeighbor(Vector2Int point)
    {
        Vector2Int neighbor;

        do
        {
            neighbor = point + directions[Random.Range(0, 4)];
        }
        while (!IsValidPoint(neighbor) || IsPointOnPath(neighbor));

        return neighbor;
    }

    private bool IsValidPoint(Vector2Int point)
    {
        return point.x >= 0 && point.x < gridSize && point.y >= 0 && point.y < gridSize;
    }

    private bool IsPointOnPath(Vector2Int point)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
            if (path[i] == point)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        DrawGrid();
        DrawPath();
        DrawStartAndEndPoints();
    }

    private void DrawGrid()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;

        for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridSize; y++)
            {
                Vector3 squarePos = new Vector3(x * squareSize, y * squareSize, 0f);
                Gizmos.DrawLine(squarePos, squarePos + new Vector3(squareSize, 0f, 0f));
                Gizmos.DrawLine(squarePos, squarePos + new Vector3(0f, squareSize, 0f));
            }
        }

        Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(gridSize * squareSize, 0f, 0f), new Vector3(gridSize * squareSize, gridSize * squareSize, 0f));
        Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(0f, gridSize * squareSize, 0f), new Vector3(gridSize * squareSize, gridSize * squareSize, 0f));
    }

    private void DrawPath()
    {
        if (path == null)
            return;

        Gizmos.color = pathColor;

        for (int i = 0; i < path.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Vector3 center1 = new Vector3(path[i].x * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, path[i].y * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, 0f);
            Vector3 center2 = new Vector3(path[i + 1].x * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, path[i + 1].y * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, 0f);

            Gizmos.DrawLine(center1, center2);
        }
    }

    private void DrawStartAndEndPoints()
    {
        if (startPoint == null || endPoint == null)
            return;

        Vector3 startPointPos = new Vector3(startPoint.x * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, startPoint.y * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, 0f);
        Vector3 endPointPos = new Vector3(endPoint.x * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, endPoint.y * squareSize + squareSize * 0.5f, 0f);

        Gizmos.color = startColor;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(startPointPos, startEndRadius);

        Gizmos.color = endColor;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(endPointPos, startEndRadius);
    }

    private void ClearGrid()
    {
        startPoint = Vector2Int.zero;
        endPoint = Vector2Int.zero;
        path = null;
    }
}
```

The result when clicking the button:

[image: random path]

the red drawn path is diagonal on the left image. in the middle image the path is diagonal and also cross over the path itself and also the start and end points on the same side of the grid. on the right another example.

what I want to make is that the start/end point will never be the same on the same side of the grid. the random path must be up,down,left,right directions not diagonal and never cross over itself.

Comment: I noticed your code includes min & max path length parameters. Is that a firm requirement? Hard min / max path length constraints make this more complex than just generating a random path & in some instances, make the problem unsolvable. For example, if the start & end points are at upper left & lower right, the shortest non diagonal path is L*W steps.

Answer (score 0):

Those funny paths are because your idea is [what's a nice word for doesn't work work and can't be made to work -- need to start over?] Your middle picture is a good example: it rolled a "5" for length. From the green-square starting space it goes 5 steps then stops in the middle of the grid. It appears to move diagonally through 3 squares after that, but it doesn't. It actually jumps to the final square because you added it to the end. The actual path is something like (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (2,2) (1,2) (0,4). Print it out to check.

The code is unfixably broken since nowhere in the code does it try to end at the blue sphere. It just wanders randomly. In fact, it could curve in on itself and get stuck in getRandomValidNeighbor since all 4 neighbors could be on the path. Making it try to reach the target in X moves involves figuring out how far it is away and how many extra spaces it need to use up. For example, if the end is 8 spaces away and it has 20 more path to use up it should prefer moving in a direction "away" from the end; but if it has 8 spaces left it needs to move in either direction towards the target. And then you'd still need to account for getting stuck.